# Attaching data-mini=true attribute to dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following code below:

```
$('<td>').append($('<input>').attr({ type: 'text', readonly: 'readonly', value: currentSet.weight }));
```

A little bit later, I append that and apply the style with:

```
.trigger('create');
```

The code works just fine.  I am also, however, trying to make that input appear mini, jquery-mobile style (i.e. as if the `<input>` had the `data-mini="true"` attribute attached).  I am not able to do this successfully.  I have tried the following methods:

```
$('<td>').append($('<input>').data('data-mini', 'true').attr({ type: 'text', readonly: 'readonly', value: currentSet.weight }));
$('<td>').append($('<input>').attr({ type: 'text', data-mini: 'true', readonly: 'readonly', value: currentSet.weight }));
```

The two lines above cause none of the javascript in the file to be executed.
I have also tried to do something like the following, where `.dynamicRow` is a `<tr>` that contains the `<td>` I am creating:

```
$('.dynamicRow').find('<input>').data('data-mini', 'true');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't prefix with `data-` when you're using `.data()`;

Try this;

```
$('<td>').append($('<input>').data('mini', true).attr({ type: 'text', readonly: 'readonly', value: currentSet.weight }));
```